# "during the month of October" vs. "during October" and "in October"

Tags: meaning

A MLB tutorial says

> if you hear
>   someone mention October baseball they
>   are likely referring to the postseason
>   as it takes place **during the month of
>   October**.

Does it still mean the same thing if I substitute "in October" or "during October" for "during the month of
October"?

Comment: Your substitutions don't change the meaning. However, I should point out that the sentence doesn't make sense anyway. If it's postseason, then it would take place **after** the end of the season. Since the end of the season is October, postseason would be **November**. So, if somebody mentions October baseball, they're *not* talking about postseason.

Comment: @JasonBassford The 2019 Major League Baseball postseason began on October 1, right?

Comment: Presumably _it_ refers to _the postseason_.

Comment: Knowing next to nothing about baseball, I had found [this](https://www.answers.com/Q/When_does_Baseball_season_begin_and_end) in a Google search: "The Major League Baseball season begins in April with Opening Day and ends in October with the World Series." Of course, that was said in 2010. Perhaps the season dates changes each year. If so, and if the postseason in the MLB tutorial is accurate only for some years, then in the years it is accurate, as @KateBunting says, *it* must be referencing *postseason*, not the end of the baseball season.

Answer (score 1):

October is a month, so 'October' and 'the month of October' are interchangeable. (Compare '2020' and 'the year 2020'.)

I don't know much about MLB, but I know that postseason baseball takes place over a period of time (?weeks, a month), so in this case there is no real difference between 'in' and 'during' (assuming that the postseason falls entirely in October).

If there is any real difference in other cases, it would be that 'during October' implies a longer period of time (it's related to 'duration'). Compare 'Our two-day seminar takes place during October' (questionable usage), 'Our one-week conference takes place during October' (acceptable) and 'Postseason baseball takes place during October' (certainly acceptable).

Contrast a birthday, which is one day. I would have to say 'my birthday is in October' not 'my birthday is during October'.